# Bharatas in Hinduism scriptures

Tags: name

I do know about three prominent Bharatas from Hindu scriptures namely  Mahabharata, Ramayana and Srimad Bhagavatam.

1. [Bharata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_(Mahabharata)) from Mahabharata was a son of Dushyanta  and Sakunthala.
2. [Bharata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_(Ramayana)) from Ramayana was a brother of Rama.
3. [Bharata](http://vedabase.net/sb/5/9/en) from Srimad Bhagavatam, popularly known as jada Bharata, who was a Jivan mukta.

Apart from the above three persons, are there any other prominent persons from Hindu scriptures having the name Bharata?

Answer (score 2):

[Bharata Chakravartin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharata_Chakravartin) is also mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam:

> Of Ṛṣabhadeva’s one hundred sons, the eldest, named Bharata, was a great, exalted devotee qualified with the best attributes. In his honor, this planet has become known as Bhārata-varṣa. ~[ŚB 5.4.9](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/4/9/)

Bharata Chakravartin's next birth was of a deer. And then deer's next birth was as Jada Bharata.

Comment: Actually he is same of Jada Bharata.  No name was mentioned during Jivan mukta state.

Comment: no..it's not same..Jada Bharata was next to next birth of Bharata Chakravartin..

Comment: Can you show the name Jada Bharata from any scripture?

Comment: what's ur comments about? You r already talking about Jada Bharata in ur Q..Bharata Chakravartin is also mentioned in Vishnu Purana..the country is named after him as per Vishnu Purana as well..

Comment: The same name of bharata chakravarti is used for the jivan muktha in his next next life. When he was in jivan muktha state, no name was given for him in scriptures afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Rig Veda mentions about ***race of Bharatas*** ([Rig Veda 3.53.12](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_3/Hymn_53))

> Praises to Indra have I sung, sustainer of this earth and heaven. This
>   prayer of Visvamitra keeps secure the ***race of Bharatas***.

However, who the Bharata, the originator of that race was and for whose sake Sage Viswamitra was praying for, is not forthcoming.

The name of this country Bharat, ie., India, might have got from this Rig Vedic Bharata only.

Comment: That also might be mentioned in vedas .

Comment: @hanugm: As far as I know, the Veda is silent on the details of Bharata.